# How do I copy dates from a different regional format in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a workbook I use to collect relevant data from a different workbook I only have read-rights to. I connected the latter to my own with Excel's built-in function "Data-connection". Copying a worksheet like this and then copying relevant data from the copied sheet is in my case (yes, I tested it) faster (by about 30%) as opposed to opening said workbook and then copying the relevant data directly from source.

The default date format in the source is "dd/mm/yy" (though it obviously adapts to the local date format settings when opening). The copied sheet keeps that date format but when copying the dates with regional settings as "english-US" Excel assumes the source format to be "yy/mm/dd" even though the cells are formatted as "dd/mm/yy".

**And here lies the problem:**
Not all users of my workbook can use the local date format of "dd/mm/yy", some have to use "mm/dd/yy" or "yy/mm/dd".

How can I tell Excel to copy from a specific date format to the local date format when the local format is not always different?

---

Checking for the local format with `Application.International(xlDateOrder)`and then changing the dates if the format differs seems like a complicated workaround which I would like to avoid.

---

The source format is `dd/mm/yy` after copying with `TargetSheet.Cells(TargetRow, TargetColumn).Value = CDate(SourceSheet.Cells(SourceRow, SourceColumn).Value)` the format was `dd/mm/yy` with days as year and year as days.

Comment: Are these dates real dates (date format) or text strings? With dates, this shoudn't be any problem (because the format is just the representation, internally it is a numeric value). With textstring, however, you will probably face a lot of issues

Comment: It might depend on how exactly you are copying. To what extent do you use VBA to do this? If you're using it at all, please include the relevant code. But as a starter, `CDate` typecasting seems intelligent enough to catch many formats (and converts it to local format), and `Format` can fix certain variants of this problem that for some reason isn't automatically picked up by `CDate`: `TargetWorksheet.Range("A1").Value = CDate(Format(SourceWorksheet.Range("A1"), "dd/mm/yy"))`

Comment: @FunThomas They must be copied as textstrings even though the function states formatting is copied also, otherwise I can't explain what's going on here.

Comment: @Vegard Please write that as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might depend on how exactly you are copying the data.

In your case it isn't entirely clear to me what your source data looks like, but for instances where typecasting dates with `CDate` isn't sufficient to make Excel infer the correct format by itself, you should be able to force the correct interpretation using [`Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications):

```
TargetSheet.Range("A1").Value = _ 
    CDate(Format(SourceSheet.Range("A1").Value, "dd/mm/yy"))
```

Do note that you might encounter datasets where you'll need to tweak this method (for example data with varying formats or particular formats that are ill suited for Excel's algorithm for understanding the conversion).

In some instances (text conversion maybe), you may have to apply the format afterwards. That is, applying `Format` to a `CDate` object instead of the other way around. I haven't looked this up in any significant extent and can't provide specific details or examples, but I am mentioning it so that you'll be on the look-out.

I am also unsure to what extent this approach will work for source formats that are outside the "english-US" format that is standard in VBA.